# Why there is a type inference error in this sample

Tags: f#

I'm getting "Lookup on object of indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point" error on this snippet:

```
let a = [|"a"; "bb"|]
let n = Array.mapi (fun i x -> (i * x.Length)) a
```

What is wrong with it? Visual Studio F# Interactive correctly shows the type of x as string when I hover the cursor above it. Why do I have to write:

```
let a = [|"a"; "bb"|]
let n = Array.mapi (fun i (x:string) -> (i * x.Length)) a
```

to compile successfully?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type checker works from left to right. Due to this reason, the compiler doesn't have enough information to infer a proper type for `x`.

The easiest way to overcome this problem is to place `a` in the beginning:

```
let n = a |> Array.mapi (fun i x -> (i * x.Length))
```

The compiler will know that `a` has type of `string []`, and therefore, `x` is of `string`.

Another alternative is using static functions:

```
let n = Array.mapi (fun i x -> (i * String.length x)) a
```

`String.length` takes a `string`, and so `string` becomes an inferred type for `x`.

Comment: That explains why compiler would have a problem with it, but why VS IntelliSense has no problem inferring the type? Is it smarter than the compiler?